# Linux Server vs Local NodeJS versions

Tags: node.js, version, google-compute-engine

Hi there fellow stackoverflow-ers,

Just a quick question hopefully.

Why is it that the latest NodeJS version for windows/mac etc is v6.9.1
however
On a google compute engine VM instance the latest version is v0.10.48
(after running sudo apt-get install nodejs)

Why are they different? Is it just the default version that comes with the VM and running the above command installs it from a local install file?
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Updated Node based on another Stackoverflow answer:

cd /usr/local/src
sudo wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.8.21/node-v0.8.21.tar.gz
sudo tar -xvzf node-v0.8.21.tar.gz
cd node-v0.8.21
sudo ./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo which node